# Xampp on windows server trying php run a python script

Tags: python, php

I am trying to execute a python script from php on windows server.
I have read tutorials and answers here in SO but I can not make it work.

My Script is:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('c:/Windows/py.exe c:/xampp/htdocs/python.py');
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

But it does not work.

I also tried

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('c:/xampp/htdocs/python.py');
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

also moved the python file where php.exe and tried

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('python.py');
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

and also

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('c:/Windows/py.exe c:/xampp/htdocs/python.py');
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

But nothing of the above works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$command= 'python.py ';
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Sorry this did not worked. Finnaly we come to a workaround by scheduling a job which generates the token and stores it in a text file before the previous token expires. Then the php sites reads the token from this text file.
Thanks for your time.